# Get list ReflectionProperty from doctrine proxy object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, proxy-classes

Example i got a proxy object from Doctrine manager.

```
// $entity is an proxy object from doctrine
$relectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($entity);
$properties = $class->getProperties();
```

`$properties` will return us an empty array, because it reflected from doctrine proxy object.

How i can get list of all properties from my object if it's an doctrine proxy object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reflect the real class instead of the proxy.

Try this (not tested):

```
$realClass = \Doctrine\Common\Util\ClassUtils::getRealClass(get_class($entity));
$properties = (new \ReflectionClass($realClass))->getProperties();
```

Comment: awesome. i was not aware of `ClassUtils::getRealClass()`. Problem solved. i owe you bro.